# Power Query - error while missing file when loading folder

Tags: excel, powerquery

I get an error:

`"Expression.Error: There weren't enough elements in the enumeration to complete the operation"`

while loading files from folder if there is no table after filtering by name.

```
let
    Source = Folder.Files("C:\Users\maciej.maniak\Documents\1. COM40 i CORRECT\Projekty\Paczesny\Plany"),
    #"Filtered rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each [Name] = "UT1"),
```

Is there a way to check if any table exists to continue query or skip it?

Edit according to Aleksei Zhigulin: I have polish version of ms excel, Źródło means Source. I made correction the the given code.

Answer (score 0):

It's look like the table in your second step should be Source, not Źródło.